# Linked Field Validation

Tags: 2010, validation

I have two fields within a list which should be dependent upon each other.  When the user creates/edits a list item I need to ensure that if one of the two fields has a value then the other is mandatory.  If both fields are blank then this is also valid.

I'm open to solutions involving OOTB SharePoint or JavaScript but at this point cannot use custom code.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.  Unfortunately we don't have the enterprise version so InfoPath forms aren't an option.  I like the validation approach but [Col1] for me is a 'Person or Group' field, which won't play nice.

Is form validation possible through JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas in validation settings of the list to do the validation of fields. Navigate to List -> List Settings -> Click on Validation Settings.

Assuming you have two columns named Col1, Col2 (of type single line text), you can use below formula

```
=OR(AND(LEN([Col1])>0,LEN([Col2])>0),AND(LEN([Col1])=0,LEN([Col2])=0))
```

You can type any descriptive message in the user message field. 
Note that formula above assumes both fields as single line text.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this functionality by customizing your list using Info path designer and by adding rules to one of the fields.